# List of items based on a dropdown selection

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am trying to list all the locations my teammates look after. I need help with my formula.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$175,MATCH(0,IF($K$2=$D$2:$D$175,COUNTIF($L$2:$L2,$B$2:$B$175),""),0))
```

[image]

Some have 1 location and others have as much as 34.
What I want to accomplish is that when I select, in this example Jose Y, it will show all 34 properties that he looks out for.

Answer (score 2):

based on your uploaded image use:

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(A:A, C:C=E2))
```

or not joined:

```
=QUERY(A:C, "select A where C = '"&E2&"'", 0)
```